# Formal methods for software defect investigation?

Tags: process, defect

Are there any formal techniques/tools/approaches to software defect investigation?

For context, I'm looking at ways to approach intermittent failure in large distributed systems with many variables to consider.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Techniques such as the five whys, fault tree analysis, and related quality tools are useful for performing root cause analysis. However, root cause analysis requires an understanding of what is causing the issue. Since you are currently facing an intermittent failure without a known trigger, you could not answer questions about why the trigger went undetected in testing or why the mistake was injected in the first place.

It sounds like you don't have enough information about the problem. I can't think of any formal techniques or processes that can be applied at this point that aren't highly dependent on your system and available tooling, but it seems like you need more information. This may involve making changes to improve observability into the system. If you have a complex distributed system, it would be helpful to have insights into log messages being generated or the messages being sent between components or performance of the system. Introducing the ability to collect additional data can help you understand when failures happen and what the triggers are. Once you understand the problem, you can fix it and then apply root cause analysis techniques to prevent similar defects from being injected or improve the ability to detect defects before they are deployed.